# Line Plot Legend Obstructing View, Move it Outside?

Tags: latex, tikz

This question looks similar to mine, but isn't about Latex: [Legend outside the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761032/legend-outside-the-plot)

I made a line plot in Latex using tikzpicture with the package pgfplots. Unfortunately, as can be seen, the legend is obstructing the view.[image]

Can I move it out of the way? Say to the right, out of the plot area?

Thanks

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413237/get-legend-outside-plot-on-tikz-and-customise-axis-labels). PS: don't forget to give a MWE for more help.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
every axis legend/.append style={ at={(0.05,0.95)}, anchor=north west,legend columns = 1
```

in the pgfplotset{} should do it!

The anchor tells the legend which corner it wants to give coordinates to, and the coordinates in "append style ={ at = {(x,y)} }" tells that corner where you want it to go.

I usually just fiddle around with numbers until I like what I see, but you can use the general rule that between 0 and 1 is inside the plot and more than 1 is outside. So for example, if you want it just to the right of where it currently is, but outside the plot, you might use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
every axis legend/.append style={ at={(1.05,0.95)}, anchor=north west,legend columns = 1}}
\begin{axis}
... rest of plotting ...
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```